# Change a background color from frames to new window

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I wanted to change background color of new window by selecting from frame. If we select any one of radio button, one new window has to open, and that window background color should be the selected button color. can anyone help me how to solve this..I don't know where i am going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
<title> Frames and Window </title>
<script>

function openWindowWithColor() {
  var color = this.getAttribute("data-color");
  console.debug("Open new window with color: " + color);
  var myNewWindow = window.open();
  myNewWindow.document.body.style.background = color;
} 
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("change", openWindowWithColor);
}
</script>

    <body>

    <p style="color:red ; font-size:15pt"> Choose the background color for new window:
        </p>               
        </br></br> 
    <label for="red">Red</label>
<input type="radio" id="red" name="windowcolor" data-color="red" />
<label for="green">Green</label>
<input type="radio" id="green" name="windowcolor" data-color="green" />
<label for="blue">Blue</label>
<input type="radio" id="blue" name="windowcolor" data-color="blue" />

      <br></br>
      <input  type="button" id = "submit" name="" style="color: green; font-size:20pt" value="submit"  size ="10" onclick="openWindowWithColor()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace myNewWindow.document.body.style.background = color; with myNewWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line
 `myNewWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript to this and it should work:

```
function openWindowWithColor() {
var color = this.getAttribute("data-color");
console.debug("Open new window with color: " + color);
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
} 

var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { 
radios[i].addEventListener("change", openWindowWithColor); 
}
```

It will open a 200x100px window with the selected color.